# Same component on 2 different GPPs

Tags: redhawksdr

I am working with a REDHAWK 1.9, Linux GPP, and a ARM GPP.

I have a waveform that includes components across multiple GPPs. In this waveform, I have the same component (with same name) running on the Linux GPP and the ARM GPP.  I have 2 different directories for this component on the host PC (Linux - running Domain Manager). I have one that is compiled on Linux (X86) and one compiled on ARM. The problem I have occurs when I create the Waveform with the IDE. Using the IDE it only sees one component vs. two. I am not able to put the same component to run on Linux and another instance of the component to run on ARM in the waveform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you attempt to launch the waveform, select your waveform and then hit the Next button twice.  On this screen, you should be able to specify which Device you would like each component to run on.  If both your x86 and your arm implementation of the component are installed to Target SDR, then the waveform should launch and correctly place your components on the selected GPP.  This can then be verified by simply running top on each machine

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. It fails to create application since it can not satisfy device dependencies for component. I have 2 different directories, one with the ARM implementation and one with the X86 implementation. The corresponding spd.xml file tells which processor it requires via the processor name.

Comment: In the waveform sad.xml, only one componentfile is given. This componentfile is where the waveform points to the directory of the component. The two instances of the component are defined in the partitioning section. To make it work for me, I had to hand edit the .sad.xml file to include additional componentfile pointing to the other directory.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have two versions of the component, one for x86/x86_64, and the other for arm.  If I'm wrong, let me know.  The way we normally do it is to have a single component and using the implementations tab of the *.spd.xml file, add a new implementation for your target arch.  You can then specify the OS and/or Processor(s) for that particular implementation.  If you then regenerate the component it will produce a new directory for your source.  If there are no code differences then just copy the code from the previous implementation

Comment: How do I launch the waveform outside of the IDE and tell it where to run the component? I currently use python commands in a script to launch the waveform.

Comment: That's a good question.  After playing around with it for a little while, I'm not positive how to do this, nor am I sure whether or not it's possible without writing a custom waveform launcher.  I would suggest asking it as a standalone question and seeing if someone else has a solution