# How to start a waveform from a python script, if a component is run on two different architectures?

Tags: redhawksdr

I had asked an earlier question on how to create and run the same component on different architecture, [Same component run on 2 different GPPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390340/same-component-on-2-different-gpps). The IDE can create a component that can run on two different architectures via the implementation tab. When you launch the waveform, you have the option to specify a particular GPP for a component instance.

How would you do the same thing when you are not launching the waveform from the IDE? I currently launch waveforms from a python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by passing a `DeviceAssignmentSequence` as the third argument to the `ApplicationFactory::create()` call.

Each member of the sequence is a `DeviceAssignmentType` that takes two string parameters.  The first is the Component's `usagename` as it appears in the SAD file.  The second is the identifier for the Device that you would like to deploy your Component to.

An example:

```
from ossie.utils import redhawk
from ossie.cf import CF
dom = redhawk.attach("REDHAWK_DEV")

# Find the devices
for devMgr in dom.devMgrs:
    # Check the name of  Device Manager
    if devMgr.name == 'DEV_MGR1':
        # Find the GPP
        for dev in devMgr.devs:
            if dev.name == 'GPP'
                dev1 = dev
    elif devMgr.name == 'DEV_MGR2':
        # Find the GPP
        for dev in devMgr.devs:
            if dev.name == 'GPP'
                dev2 = dev

# Create the deployment requirements
# First variable is comp name as it appears in the SAD file, second is device ID
assignment1 = CF.DeviceAssignmentType('comp_1', dev1._get_identifier())
assignment2 = CF.DeviceAssignmentType('comp_2', dev2._get_identifier())

# Install the Application Factory
dom.installApplicationFactory('/waveforms/app_name/app_name.sad.xml')

# Get the Application Factory
facs = dom._get_applicationFactories()
# If using multiple, different Applications, this list needs to be iterated
# to get the correct factory
app_fac = facs[0]

# Create the Application
app = app_fac.create(app_fac._get_name(), [], [assignment1, assignment2])

# Uninstall the Application Factory
dom.uninstallApplication(app_fac._get_identifier())
```